# $.fancybox is not a function with Angular

Tags: angular, fancybox

I'm having an issue with using Fancybox in an Angular application.

The issue happens when I try to programatically open a div in a fancybox, which results in me getting an error `$.fancybox is not a function`

I've included jQuery and fancybox in my packages like this (package.json)

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@fancyapps/fancybox": "^3.5.7",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

And included in my angular project like this (angular.json)

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "Client": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              ...
              "node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              ...
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"
            ]
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
}
```

I know that fancybox is being loaded correctly because when I use the `data-fancybox` attribute I can get a fancybox to display correctly. Like this

```
<a data-fancybox href="#myDivId" data-options='{ "touch" : false}'>
    <button>
        Open My Div
    </button>
</a>

<div id="myDivId" style="display: none;">
    My Div
</div>
```

But I occasionally want to open my div programatically. Supposedly I can do it like this with jQuery, but it's not working

```
// html
<div id="myDivId" style="display: none;">
    My Div
</div>

<button (click)="openMyDiv()">
    Open My Div
</button>

// declared at top of ts file
declare var $: any;

// open function in ts file, I get an error after this executes
openMyDiv() {
    $.fancybox({
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
        'transitionOut': 'elastic',
        'speedIn': 500,
        'speedOut': 300,
        'autoDimensions': true,
        'centerOnScroll': true,
        'href' : '#myDivId'
     }); 
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... It looks like fancybox is loaded correctly, but somehow jQuery doesn't have the fancybox function??

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you were to inspect the variable $ what does it show, and what sort of options does it have? Perhaps this post may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342935/fancybox-in-angular-2

Comment: Have you tried using `window.jQuery` instead of `$` ?

Comment: @SomeStudent thanks for the advice. Indeed I was not able to find `fancybox` when inspecting `$`. I was, however, able to find it when inspecting `window.jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Janis for this. I was able to find fancybox using `window.jQuery.fancybox...`

Here's how I'm launching my fancybox div now:

```
openMyDiv() {
    window.jQuery.fancybox.open({
        'src' : '#myDivId'
    });
}
```